# Update script var's with value from drop down?

Tags: javascript

I have a script, which basically looks like this (the part I need help with):

```
<script>
var languageFrom = " from ";
var languageTo = " to ";
</script>
```

If I had a drop down menu that looked like this:

```
<select>
<option value="en">En</option>
<option value="fr">Fr</option>
</select>
```

When you select one of the drop down menus, it populates the `from` variable with the text from the option value. How can you accomplish this? Are there any tutorials on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a `change` event handler to the `select` element:

```
document.getElementById("yourSelect").onchange = function() {
    languageFrom = this.value;
}
```

Note that this assumes an `id` of `yourSelect` on the `select` element, and also assumes that `languageFrom` is in the scope of the event handler function (probably global).

Comment: This would work for one variable, but what if there were 2, like in my code? So one drop down would control the first var and the second drop down would control the second var.

Comment: Just bind a `change` event handler to the other `select` element, exactly as shown in my answer.

Comment: Yeah exactly like that, but don't forget to declare the `languageFrom` and `languageTo` variables (which you have done in your question but not in the fiddle).

Comment: That's what I left out! How do I then fill the variable with what was changed in on change function?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. In your fiddle, if you declare the variables outside of the event handler functions they will in scope inside of the functions and their values will be changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4756/discussion-between-charlie-and-james-allardice)

Answer (score 0):

```
selectNode.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
        languageFrom=languageTo;
        languageTo = evt.target.value;
    },false);
```

Comment: Why is `langaugeFrom` being set equal to `languageTo`?